# How to plot expression in x axes and variable in y axes

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[1.88 (a^(1/3)) , {a,-0.56,0.56}]
```

I unable to plot the expression in x axes and variable in y axes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I got what you are asking, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
ParametricPlot[{1.88 (a^(1/3)), a}, {a, -0.56, 0.56}]
```

You have a varying on the y axis and 1.88 (a^(1/3)) varying on the x axis.

Comment: Found what I am looking for.Thank you